# Detect a parameter change in a foreign website

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, monitoring

Let's suppose we have a read-only website, containing a button

```
<div class="with-a-class">
    <div property="value">
        <table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>
                    <button>
                        <img src="static/first.gif">
                    </button>
                </td>
                <!-- Some more table cells-->
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to detect any change if the button's `src` property and print it whenever changed: (pseudocode)

```
onSrcChanged: console.log(src)
```

I'm using Firefox.

Comment: Not possibly because that would be a huge security concern otherwise. [Why don't you instead tell us the actual problem you are trying to solve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect change in the src

```
// This is your image
var target = document.querySelector('#myImage');

// This is the observer
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations)
{
    // Loop all changes
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation)
    {
        // Only if src was changed
        if(mutation.attributeName=='src')
        {
            // Print the new value
            console.log(mutation.target.src);
        }
    });    
});

// Read only changes in the attributes
var config = { attributes: true, childList: false, characterData: false };

// Initialize the Observer
observer.observe(target, config);
```